# pdf tounicode maps cid to incorrect character

Tags: pdf, unicode, pdf-generation

I am trying to parse a PDF file with a very odd ToUnicode CMap. It maps CID into a unicode that is wrong, but Preview on Mac or Acrobat can show it correctly.

Here is the Page object:

```
7 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Page
  /Parent 1 0 R
  /MediaBox [ 0 0 595.5 842.25 ]
  /Group <<
    /Type /Group
    /S /Transparency
    /CS /DeviceRGB
  >>
  /Resources <<
    /Font <<
      /F0 4 0 R
      /F1 5 0 R
      /F2 6 0 R
    >>
    /XObject <<
      /Im0 2 0 R
    >>
    /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageC ]
  >>
  /Contents 3 0 R
>>
endobj
```

This is excerpt of the Contents object, which reads like `Client Name:`:

```
3 0 obj
<<
  /Length 2490
  /Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
q
294.80 0 0 45.35 40.19 768.05 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
q
39.44 665.25 106.38 15.67 re
W
n
/F0 11 Tf
0.00 0.00 0.00 rg
BT
41.69 538.82 Td
<0012016F015D011E0176019A0003004501020175011E0357> Tj
ET
...
```

This is the Font /F0 object:

```
4 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Font
  /Subtype /Type0
  /BaseFont /Calibri
  /Encoding /Identity-H
  /DescendantFonts [ 12 0 R ]
  /ToUnicode 10 0 R
>>
endobj
```

And, this is the excerpt of ToUnicode object of the Font /F0 object:

```
10 0 obj
<<
  /Length 584
  /Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Ordering (Identity)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Calibri def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
67 beginbfchar
<0012> <0043>
<016F> <006C>
<015D> <0001>
<011E> <0065>
<0176> <0001>
<019A> <0074>
<0003> <0020>
<0045> <004E>
<0102> <0061>
<0175> <0001>
<0357> <003A>
...
```

With this ToUnicode CMap, the characters in the text above turns into `Cl\x01e\x01t Na\x01e:`, with a bunch of `\x01` embedded, while the rest are normal. However, in Acrobat, this text is shown correctly.

How does Acrobat parse the text correctly? And what can I do to retrieve the correct text in unicode? Thanks.

Comment: *"However, in Acrobat, this text is shown correctly."* - do you mean that Acrobat *displays* the correct glyphs or does *copy&paste* from it return the correct unicode characters?

Answer (score 3):

The rendering of the text is entirely independent of the ToUnicode CMap. The ToUnicode Cmap is used **only** to take character codes and return the corresponding Unicode code point.

The rendering of the text is done by taking the same character code and mapping it through various methods depending on the type of the font. In your case this is a CIDFont with an Identity-H CMap, so the character codes map directly to CIDs, and (assuming the descendant font is a TrueType font) to TrueType GIDs.

The GID is then used to retrieve the character outline and render the glyph. The ToUnicode isn't used at all in rendering the text, it's only used for copy/paste/search.

Try doing a copy/paste of the text from Acrobat, I believe this will demonstrate the same problem you note above.

I'm afraid that if the ToUnicode CMap is wrong, there is no reliable way to retrieve the text. There are heuristics you can follow, and in this case the fact that the CIDFont uses an Identity-H CMap means you could 'probably' use the CMAP subtable embedded in the TrueType font to give you the Unicode value. In general though, there is no real way to tell that a ToUnicode CMap is incorrect.